# Store data in Application class when I open application second time

Tags: android

I store data in my application class

```
public class VApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public Double getGrandTotal() {
    return grandTotal;
}

public Double setGrandTotal(Double grandTotal) {
    this.grandTotal = grandTotal;
    return grandTotal;
}
public  Double grandTotal = 0.0;
}
```

I use  setGrandTotal() and getGrandTotal() method in other activity to store data its work fine, 
my problem is when I close application an start again than grand total becomes 0.0,
I want to store data in grand total when I open appliction second time.

Comment: You need to store data on sharedpreference bcz application store data or static will be clear on app crash or low memory.

Comment: @payal There are multiple ways to achieve this.if your data is not big size then you can prefer shared Preference and else you to store in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Double getGrandTotal() {
    if (grandTotal == 0) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("config", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString("grandTotal", "0");
        grandTotal = Double.valueOf(value);
    }
    return grandTotal;
}

public Double setGrandTotal(Double grandTotal) {
    this.grandTotal = grandTotal;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("config", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("grandTotal", String.valueOf(grandTotal)).apply();
    return grandTotal;
}

public Double grandTotal = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should store your data in a Database or Cache of your app. i recommend you to use SharedPreferences

Below are the useful links to help you

[SharedPreferences|Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[Tutorials Point Shared Preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)